# Can one strengthen the Lagrangian dual bound in column generation when there are multiple subproblems?

Tags: linear-programming, column-generation, reduced-costs, pricing

Consider a Linear Programme (LP)
\begin{align}
\min && \sum_{i \in I} c_i x_i \\
\text{s.t.} && \sum_{i \in I} a_{ij} x_i &\geq b_j & \quad & \forall j \in J \\
&& x_i &\geq 0 & \quad & \forall i \in I
\end{align}

Assume you are solving this problem via column generation.
Let $z$ be the value of the optimal solution of the **reduced** problem (RLP), i.e., the problem obtained when only considering a subset of the variables, $I' \subsetneq I$.
Let $\bar{c}$ be the lowest reduced cost of a variable of $I' \setminus I$ (i.e., which is not yet in RLP).
Note that $\bar{c} < 0$ unless we are at the optimum.
Finally, assume that a convexity constraint $\sum_{i \in I} x_i \leq U$ holds.

The Lagrangian bound is a dual bound on the value of the optimum $z^*$ of LP and states that it cannot be improved by more than $U$ times $\bar{c}$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
z + U \cdot \bar{c} \leq z^* \leq z
\end{equation}

Now assume that the set of variables can be partitioned as $I = I_1 \cup \ldots \cup I_k$ and that new variables can be priced solving $k$ independent subproblems.
Further assume that we have $k$ convexity constraints
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in I_\ell} x_i \leq U_\ell \quad \forall \ell \in \{1, \ldots, k\}
\end{equation}
Denote with $\bar{c}_\ell$ the lowest reduced cost given by pricing subproblem $\ell$, i.e., the lowest reduced cost of a variable in $I_\ell \setminus I'$. Is it true that the following is a valid bound?
\begin{equation}
z + \sum_{\ell = 1}^k U_\ell \cdot \bar{c}_\ell \leq z^* \leq z
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that traditionally $i$ corresponds to constraints (rows) and $j$ corresponds to variables (columns), the opposite of what you used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that bound is valid, and you can prove it by exhibiting a dual feasible solution with that objective value. I don’t have my copy handy, but Wolsey’s *Integer Programming* shows this. In fact, the bound is still valid even if $\bar{c}_\ell$ is only a lower bound on the objective value of subproblem $\ell$. That is, you can obtain a valid bound even if you stop solving a subproblem early, as is common when the subproblem is MILP instead of LP.

Comment: Another common situation when one has a lower bound on the objective value of the subproblem occurs in routing. If you solve the SP via labelling, state space relaxation provides a lower bound.